# Tensorflow: How to get the accuracy/prediction for whole test dataset? not for each batch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to use Tensorboard to visualize my testing procedure. My purpose is, when every epoch completed, I would like to test the network's accuracy using the whole test dataset, and store this accuracy result into a summary file, so that I can visualize it in Tensorboard.

Tensorflow has summary_op to do it, however (all the existing examples) seems only work for one batch when running the code sess.run(summary_op). I need to calculate the accuracy for the whole test dataset. How can I do that?

Is there any example to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate it by:

1. Batching your test dataset in case it is too large; e.g. into `n_test_batches` and start with a buffer like `buffer_accuracies = 0.0`
2. Adding the batch accuracies into the buffer variable `buffer_accuracies`
3. Finally when you processed the whole test dataset divide `buffer_accuracies` by total number of `test_batches`
4. Now you would have `test_accuracy = buffer_accuracies/n_test_batches`as a regular python variable
5. No we can create a summary for that python variable as follows

   ```
   test_accuracy_summary = tf.Summary()
   test_accuracy_summary.add(tag="test_accuracy", simple_value = test_accuracy)
   ```
6. Finally write that into your tensorflow FileWriter e.g.

   ```
   test_writer.add_summary(test_accuracy_summary,iteration_step)
   ```